# Discord.py - Why my command ban don't work?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

Hey in my code command del work normaly but i don't understand why my other command ban don't work normaly have you got one idea ?

```
def client():
    import discord
    default_intents = discord.Intents.default()
    default_intents.members = True

    client = discord.Client(intents = default_intents)
#☺démarrage du bot
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("ready !")
   
#commande de del
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        try:
            if message.content.startswith("-del"):
                number = int(message.content.split()[1])
                messages = await message.channel.history(limit = number +1).flatten()
                
                for each_message in messages:
                    await each_message.delete()
        except:
            await message.channel.send('La commande "-del"demande un nombre comme argument.')
#commande de Ban
        try:
            if message.content.startswith("-ban"):
                user: discord.User = message.content.split()[1]
                reason = message.content.split()[2][-1]
                await discord.guild.ban(user, reason = reason)
                await message.channel.send(f"{user} à été ban pour la raison : {reason}")
        except:
            await message.channel.send("La fonction '-ban' demande l'utilisateur et la raison.")
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: What do you mean by, doesn't work. Is there an error or does nothing happen? Have you tried checking the bot perms?

Comment: Nothing happens and my bot has administrative permissions but my python code does not indicate an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `await discord.guild.ban(user, reason = reason)` is wrong, the command [ban](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20ban#discord.Guild.ban) is a method of a Guild object, not the guild module, therefore it doesn't know in what guild to do the ban

The traceback is probably lost in the try/except so you can remove the try/except clause to see what is really causing the issue.

The solution would be to use the ban method on the guild object given in the message (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.guild) so it would become

```
await message.guild.ban(user, reason = reason)
```

Also, feel free to type the parameters of your function or command (`async def on_message(message):` would become `async def on_message(message: Message):` so your IDE can autocomplete better for you

Finally, you should look into [Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs) and the [command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command) decorator